Smoke alarm... Two neutral wires!
I am fitting a Ei3016 smoke alarm which is replacing an old EI150.
I removed the old alarm and on its base plate is a terminal block which includes 2 neutrals. On the back of the old smoke alarm, only one of the neutrals connects (the pin is removed).
What should I do with the spare neutral?



It appears that the concern over two neutrals comes from the wiring harness at the mounting plate having two blue wires, and one of the blue wires is labeled "neutral" on the diagram on the back of the alarm body. What do you see at the other end of the harness with the two blue wires when you take the mounting plate off and carefully pull the harness out of the hole in the drywall?

FWIW I would not be surprised to see the two blue wires wired together to the interconnect wire in the ceiling, or the blue between the brown and the white not wired to anything. This could be that the manufacturer used to wire the alarm brown/blue/white/empty and is now wiring them brown/empty/white/blue, or the harness is common to several alarm types, some wired one way, some the other way.
